# How to type object keys with array values

Tags: typescript, generics

I want to write a generic function `toTable` that forces correctly typed data like:

```js
const result = toTable(['name', 'age'], [{ name: 'Adam', age: '24' }]) // no error
const result = toTable(['name', 'age'], [{ name: 'Adam' }]) // error - missing age prop
const result = toTable(['name', 'age'], [{ name: 'Adam', age: '24', height: 70 }]) // error - extra prop
```

I think I'm close but my attempt is not working and gives no errors:

```js
toTable<T extends string[]>(columns: T, data: { [key in T[number]]: string; }[]) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if I just move the column array into the generic brackets like:

```js
const result = toTable<['name', 'age']>([{ name: 'Adam', age: '24' }]) // no error
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close indeed :)

```js
declare function toTable<T extends readonly string[]>(columns: T, data: { [key in T[number]]: string; }[]): any;

const result0 = toTable(['name', 'age'] as const, [{ name: 'Adam', age: '24' }]) // no error
const result1 = toTable(['name', 'age'] as const, [{ name: 'Adam' }]) // error - missing age prop
const result2 = toTable(['name', 'age'] as const, [{ name: 'Adam', age: '24', height: 70 }]) // error - extra prop
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwxwBUoAjCEAHiPhAA8MRVgBneOKYPCAT3hYwwsqAOYBtALoA+ABRgcEZAFtULAFzwiAGnjAoGKBoDe8MQGsQfYZrGplpEDAkSNAoaIDc8AL6SAlBpQqDweAFCh8qoY7CAsyBAYAAzwALwExGQUMmIA5KhQSiA5OjlQIkUS8FBskQI6Yib5hRo5AIJ6SsVV5S0ATAAsOT4SfvAA9GPwqDi0MDA4MBF4AjFxCQCMqekk5CDZeQVFJWUVVTXLGPWNhy3tBUPeI+OTjvMw8AC08EpYLCzCIm6CAADvNgUsoqt4hheltCDssrkmkd4KVyjlKtV4LVLqZrs1UXdOjoTn1BjoABYgLAiCkYDQAdmSj1GE1mb0+tAYMCg8FBOGBQA)

What changed ?

- First, you cannot use `['name', 'age']` as it will be considered as `string[]` by the type system. So you need to make it const/readonly to become a tuple.
- Then this tuple must be understandable by the generic in your function, so make that generic extends a readonly array instead to cover the tuple case